# Accent characters cause a slight delay in hotkey's execution of Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use `Ctrl+Alt+y` as a keybinding for `Ctrl+Right`.

```
^!y:: Send ^{Right}
```

In my keyboard, which is a Turkish F-keyboard, `AltGr+y` (or `Ctrl+Alt+y`) produces the accent character "``"`. Therefore, windows waits for the next key after pressing`Ctrl+Alt+y`to put the right accented character, such as`áé`.

Is there a way to disable the accented characters in order to stop the delay for `Ctrl+Alt+key` keybinding?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same on a Dutch computer: all ' and " are dead keys that wait for the next key. I hate that, so I have disabled this behaviour all together (I am not sure whether that is what you want). I use Autohotkey hotstrings to write all accents. For example, `e//` becomes é, `e/\` becomes ê, `c,,` becomes ç, etc. (I could give you a list of my hotstrings if you like). If you want to disable this way of writing accents only for this one combination, and if your hotkey doesn't work, then I don't know how it could be done.

This is how to disable dead-key accents all at once:

- In the control panel, go to Regional Settings/languages => Keyboards;
- Then click "change keyboards";
- Now check whether you also have English installed as a language.

  - If so, click the drop-down menu and change your language to English;
  - If not, first click Add... to add English (then pick an English or international keyboard lay-out); then change to English with the drop-down menu.
- Now delete the Turkish language that is still in the list (you can add it back in at any time later).
- Then reboot.

Note that the menus might be somewhat different on your computer (this is Win7 English).

Comment: Thank you Cerberus for the explanation. This is a good solution. But unfortunately I cannot change my keyboard layout to English.